# How to adjust the table and make to display without gaps?

Tags: html, css

[Here is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Pqs.png)

[Here how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHTJv.png)

```
`
https://codepen.io/SevastianBah/pen/VwBaPVB
`
```

I suppose that it is related some how to the big red block. In code inspector, there is no any margins or paddings for block.

Comment: Please provide debugging details in form of a [repro] not as a link to external resources! Last but not least, read the description of the tags you are using. `web` specifically states not to sue that tag. This question also has nothing to do with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code pen. You tried to demonstrate the table using nested table inside the  tag. However it can may be fulfill your target. But using colspan and rowspan property you can easily demonstrate the table.

Here I have demonstrated it using colspan rowspan. Well the concept is pretty easier. Look carefully at your targeted table. There you can easily equally divided each cells in total 4 rows and 3 columns. Where the 1st cell taken two column and two row. So we declared colspan value 2 and rowspan value 2. These will allow the cell to take two rows and two column. then the rest td will represent other cells. So as 1st td taken 2 columns and two rows so in 1st and second rows total td will be 3 and 2. but in third row each td will take one cell.

In css the border collapse will remove the spaces in between. Then you can add border to each td. Go through the code below. Hope this might help you.

```css
table{
  width: 600px; 
  height: 400px; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style='background-color: red' colspan='2' rowspan='2'></td>
      <td style='background-color: blue'></td>
      <td style='background-color: red'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='background-color: red'></td>
      <td style='background-color: blue'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style='background-color: red'></td>
      <td style='background-color: blue'></td>
      <td style='background-color: red'></td>
      <td style='background-color: blue'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and edit your answer accordingly. Code-only answers a re considered **low-quality**. Please add a sufficient description of what you did and how your changes would solve the issue.

Comment: I am really sorry. I didn't gone through his 'codepen' link which I have gone through now. I was just gone through his targeted table design. Now I have elaborately explained him. Thank you very much for making me conscious.

Answer (score -1):

Float td left:

```
td{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
.big{
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
}

.small{
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}

.red{
    background-color: red;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

div{
    border: 2px black solid;
}

td{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="big red"></div></td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="small blue"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="small red"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div class="small red"></div></td>
                        <td><div class="small blue"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="small red"></div></td>
            <td><div class="small blue"></div></td>
            <td><div class="small red"></div></td>
            <td><div class="small blue"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, actually I tried float: left but for div, not for <td>. And if it will not take your time, could you please explain how to ctach such code snippets in stackoverflow?

Comment: you should not use `float` inside a table. Despite the fact that it won't do anything useful it also breaks the purpose of a table.

Comment: @Севастиан Багинский
You can add code snippets by clicking the button next to the insert image button.  It's very intuitive and works pretty much like codepen.
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/522IS.png)